# How to store file paths on phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using `XAMPP` and I want to store image paths on my `phpmyadmin` database and I saw here: [Database design : preferred field length for file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377740/database-design-preferred-field-length-for-file-paths) that the best options to store file paths should be `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

As I cannot set `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` on my `phpmyadmin`,

How can I store these paths on my database properly? I mean, what is the best option to store them on my database?

**Edit:** I have seen the question that has been marked as possible duplicate. I know that I can "simulate" the `VARCHAR(MAX)` on `phpmyadmin` but, as it does not exist by default, it would be better to use another length instead of `MAX`?

I think that if you set a path of length 100 and you have your `MAX` as the limit is not worth so `VARCHAR(suitable number)` would be better than `VARCHAR(MAX)` (or at least I think it would be better). I am new with `MySQL` so I do not know about the entrails of it (by the moment).

I think it can be problems of performance or maybe memory but I cannot find anything on the official documentation so please if you find something related post here.

Is there a suitable length for store paths on phpmyadmin? A number of length that it is usually used (and why).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332798/equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is to create a VARCHAR(255) column.
255 because normally standard url should not exceed this size

If you can't do it directly you can try :

1) create your column as VARCHAR 
2) in the structure part you can set the size that will be the max size of your column

Comment: I can use `VARCHAR`,  what I cannot use is `VARCHAR(MAX)` on it.

Comment: a ok i understand so to do it 1) create your column as VARCHAR and then in the structure part you can set the size that will be the max size of your column

Comment: Yes I know how to put a specific size to a `VARCHAR` type but I do not know what should be the correct size for this purpose (store file paths).

Comment: a ok the best size for file path is on my view 255 character.
in fact a standard url should normally not exceed this size.