# Converting ntext to nvcharmax(max) - Getting around size limitation

Tags: sql, nvarchar

I'm trying to change an existing SQL **NText** column to **nvcharmax(max)**, and encountering an error on the size limit. There's a large amount of existing data, some of which is more than the 8k limit, I believe.

We're looking to convert this, so that the field is searchable in LINQ.

The 2x SQL statements I've tried are:

```
update Table
set dataNVarChar = convert(nvarchar(max), dataNtext)
where dataNtext is not null

update Table
set dataNVarChar = cast(dataNtext as nvarchar(max))
where dataNtext is not null
```

And the error I get is:

```
Cannot create a row of size 8086 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
```

This is using SQL Server 2008.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

---

### Update / Solution:

The marked answer below is correct, and SQL 2008 can change the column to the correct data type in my situation, and there are no dramas with the LINQ-utilising application we use on top of it:

```
alter table [TBL] alter column [COL] nvarchar(max)
```

I've also been advised to follow it up with:

```
update [TBL] set [COL] = [COL]
```

Which completes the conversion by moving the data from the lob structure to the table (if the length in less than 8k), which improves performance / keeps things proper.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is most likely because the column dataNVarChar is not defined as NVARCHAR(max)
To convert a column from NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX), use this

```
alter table TBL alter column COL nvarchar(max)
```

It will perform the conversion of the data in the column for you at the same time

Comment: To clarify, the dataNVarChar column is specified as NVarChar(MAX). I have however found this happens in SQL 2008, and not 2008 R2...

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701808/should-i-use-an-inline-varcharmax-column-or-store-it-in-a-separate-table on outlining the varchar(max) column. It could be a bug in 2008 that attempts to store the data inline, since it works in 2008 R2 (and should in 2005). If possible at all, a cold migration of the column type ALTER COLUMN may work as well, instead of a 2nd column.

Comment: That does sound like it has to be a bug. Columns defined as max *should* be automatically stored out of row if it would overflow the max row size. You can explicitly tell SQL server to store large data types out of row by using this: EXEC sp_tableoption 'yourtablename', 'large value types out of row', 1;